# How to get array of objects with unique values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How to sum object array with the same key value?

I have this array:

```
let arrData = [{ category: "Main Expenses", amount: 420 },
    { category: "Food", amount: 50 },
    { category: "Main Expenses", amount: 4530},
    { category: "Food", amount: 4520 },
    { category: "Main Expenses", amount: 4530 },
    { category: "Food", amount: 450 },
    { category: "Self Care", amount: 7540 },
    { category: "Child Care", amount: 4570 }]
```

And I need to get array with unique categories, like this:

```
[Main Expenses: 9480,
Food: 5020,
Self Care: 7540,
Child Care: 4570]
```

Comment: Your *"like this"* array is not valid JavaScript. So, before people start trying to answer your question, please edit it and make clear what's your expected outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected output is in array is not possible since array will not support key & value pair. You may opt for object.

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and check if the object contains the `key` by category name. If so then add the amount otherwise create key by the category name and set its value to the amount

```js
let arrData = [{
    category: "Main Expenses",
    amount: 420
  },
  {
    category: "Food",
    amount: 50
  },
  {
    category: "Main Expenses",
    amount: 4530
  },
  {
    category: "Food",
    amount: 4520
  },
  {
    category: "Main Expenses",
    amount: 4530
  },
  {
    category: "Food",
    amount: 450
  },
  {
    category: "Self Care",
    amount: 7540
  },
  {
    category: "Child Care",
    amount: 4570
  }
]

let newData = arrData.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.category] = acc[item.category] ?
    acc[item.category] + item.amount :
    item.amount;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: @sandrooco pls make sure that you don't change the answer context while editing

Comment: @Shubh What does changing the answer context mean in that case?

Comment: When i upvoted the answer was working properly ,after you edited it started giving Nan,I dint quite saw what yoou edited @sandrooco

Comment: @brk,I guess the question asks for array and your result returns an object ,probably user wants two dim array ?

Comment: 1. It was some other dude's edit that gave `NaN`.
2. You can see all edits by clicking on "edited x minutes ago".
3. There's nothing about context, it's just not working properly.
4. I suppose @Kate needs an object to know about the categories' keys.